# Horn activated itself with engine off / passenger ac hot

Tags: chevrolet, ac, tahoe, horn

2004 Chevy Tahoe:
Car's horn went off on its own, and wouldn't stop until I pulled the fuse. This was a continuous sound of the horn. Not short honks. Vehicle was parked in my garage and the engine was off. Initially, I tried to use my key-fob's lock/unlock and panic feature, but that did nothing to stop the horn. I also started, and then turned off the engine, but that also failed to quiet the horn. When I went to put the fuse back in in the morning the horn went off again. I left the fuse out and started the vehicle and turned on the AC. I then noticed that hot air was blowing out of the passenger vents while cold air was blowing out of the drivers vent. Maybe a coincidence, maybe related. I don't know. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Wow, that sounds you have short in your electrical system somewhere. Asking "*Any ideas?*" is too broad for the format of this site, which is for asking specific questions. You have to start troubleshooting it, or take it to someone who can, to find out what is happening. Then update us with what you find. We can try to help from there.

Comment: "You have to start troubleshooting it, or take it to someone who can, to find out what is happening. Then update us with what you find."  No offense, but if I did that I wouldn't be here asking for input.

Comment: Try plugging the horn in (yah, it'll be loud while you do it) and seeing if the passenger side AC decides to work, but I'll bet you these are two separate issues. Do you have the Auto A/C feature in your Tahoe (where you set the dash to a number and it cools/heats left right as you have it set), or are they manual settings? I take it they are split temps?

Comment: The AC issue seems to have resolved itself. Now it's back to working fine. I still have the horn issue. Thanks for your input.

Comment: I read online someone else with the same issue ('01 Tahoe), found the issue to be with the horn button. They pulled up on the button itself to solve it temporarily.

Comment: Yes, I've seen that also. But it seems that the "horn button" would more likely be the culprit if I actually hit the horn, and then the horn stayed on. The horn coming on with no one in the vehicle sort of makes the horn button less likely ... or not. It's very difficult to nail issues down when they're intermittent.  Thank you for the idea though.

Comment: If you have a multimeter it'll lead you to what's wrong next time the horn acts up. It's a 4 pin relay with two terminals always hot, an output terminal to the horn that will always be grounded (until powered) if the circuits intact. Then the BCM or horn switch controlled relay coil ground. Generally relays are numbered on the bottom and have a wiring diagram on the side.

Answer (score 1):

I would replace the horn relay. Should be in the fuse box under the hood. If you have your owners manual can you tell us which fuse you pulled?the owners manual will indicate if the fuse had anything to do with the a.c.

Comment: I pulled the small 15 amp fuse for the horn next to the horn relay. I put the fuse back in, and now the horn is okay (for now). The AC is still okay. It may have been due to the extreme humidity we are experiencing here in the Houston area. There were also thunderstorms and lightning in the area about the time the horn malfunctioned. Could be related ... or not. Thank you for your time and input! Much appreciated! If it happens again I'll look at the horn relay.

Comment: Addendum:  I put the fuse back in after I drove the vehicle. The heat of the engine may have removed any condensation caused by the humidity (if that was the problem to begin with).